# How to align title, description and URL in an equal space

Tags: java, android

Here is a screenshot of the layout as it currently appears on my screen:

[image]

Here is the XML code snippet for the layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="-10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:height="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="Cabin-Regular"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#E35B5B"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:height="44dp"
        android:fontFamily="Cabin-Regular"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="100dp"
        android:textColor="#2D2D2D"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/url_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:height="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="80dp"
        android:textColor="#BDBDBD"
        android:textSize="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I just want to have the three textviews properly aligned and have equal space among each other.

Comment: Why are u not using the LinearLayout in it , use the property of weightSum of linearlayot than it will work

Comment: Because obviously for such things RelativeLayout is better ... you can't do this(image on the right, and 3 lines of text) with a single LinearLayout

Comment: @Selvin ...But the LinearLayout approach is better (As i think) ..Use the LinearLayout divide in into two part using weight sum and than in first part it should divide it into 3 parts ..What do you think sir ??

Comment: obviously you are wrong .. multiple LinearLayouts instead single RelativeLayout as ListView items will cause performance problems please read official guides/trainings before writing "what you think" http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your layout,

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="-10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/icon"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="Cabin-Regular"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="#E35B5B"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="Cabin-Regular"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textColor="#2D2D2D"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/url_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="URL"
            android:textColor="#BDBDBD"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what did you change? What is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36003207/edit), not here in comments (*** *** ***without*** *** ***  "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

Use the same `paddingLeft` for all tests and `layout_below` like below:

```xml
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/url_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/desc"
    android:height="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="80dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="url"
    android:textColor="#BDBDBD"
    android:textSize="10dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code. Try maximum to use `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`. `RelativeLayout` is used in cases where two or more elements have to be overlapped each other. Don't include every elements in a single layout. Divide your design into different sections, and use LinearLayout for each section and within each section, and include elements belonging to that section.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="#E35B5B"
            android:fontFamily="Cabin-Regular"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Google"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="#2D2D2D"
            android:fontFamily="Cabin-Regular"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Google is a Search engine"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/url_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:textColor="#BDBDBD"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="http://www.google.com"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"

        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `android:weight=""` to a child of a relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

Create a *LinearLayout* for title, description and URL with a vertical orientation and weightsum=3 in Layout and for each of them use width=wrap_content, height=0dp, weight=1.

Answer (score 0):

First remove `android:height` from each `TextView`. In the last `TextView`, you have set `android:layout_marginTop="50`. Remove it.

**Tip**: Use `LinearLayout` if you want to show all your views vertically or horizontally. If you want to use `RelativeLayout`, make sure you give margin and padding properly so they look good.

Answer (score 0):

Use Linear layout as the parent with weightsum and equally distribute weight among the child layouts. Example: If `android:weightsum = "3"` for the parent and then `android:layout_weight = "1"` for each child layout (if you want equal space for each one of the three children).

PS: don’t forget to mention orientation for `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score -1):

Just check this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#E35B5B"
            android:fontFamily="Cabin-Regular"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:text="Google"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="#2D2D2D"
            android:fontFamily="Cabin-Regular"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:margin_top="5dp"
            android:text="Google is a Search engine"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/url_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="#BDBDBD"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:margin_top="5dp"
            android:text="http://www.google.com"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do or accomplish? What did you change and why?